# Counting repeated characters around nth character of string

Tags: regex, perl

For a part of my University project, i am trying to count base repeats around the 11th character of 21 bp sequences of DNA. I want to look at the 11th character, then if there are repeated identical characters around it, to print them.

For example:

```
GCTAAAGTAAAAGAAGATGCA
```

Would give results of:

```
11th base is A, YES repeated 4 times
```

I really don't know how to go about this, to get the 11th character i'm sure i can use a regex but after that i'm not sure.

To start with I have playing around using a hash and looking for the number of occurrences of different nucleotide groups in each sequence, as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $outputfile = "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/hash.txt";

open FILE1, "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/randomoutput.txt";

open( OUTPUTFILE, ">$outputfile" );

while (<FILE1>) {
    if (/^(\S+)/) {

        my $dna     = $1;
        my @repeats = ( $dna =~ /[A]{3}/g );
        my @changes = ( $dna =~ /[T]{2}/g );

        my %hash  = ();
        my %hash1 = ();

        for my $repeats (@repeats) {
            $hash{$repeats}++;
        }
        for my $changes (@changes) {
            $hash1{$changes}++;
        }

        for my $key ( keys %hash ) {
            print OUTPUTFILE $key . " =>  " . $hash{$key} . "\n";
        }
        for my $key1 ( keys %hash1 ) {
            print OUTPUTFILE $key1 . " =>  " . $hash1{$key1} . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

FILE1 data:

```
ATTTTTAGCCGAACAAGTACC
TACTTAGTTAAATTGTTACAA
ATAAACCTTGTGCAGGTTTGT
CCTTAATCCTTGTATTTTTAA
TCTTGTTAAAATGTCTACAGG
ATGTTAGTTATTTCATTCTTC
AAGTAACTAAAATTGCTCAAT
ACATTCGACAAAAATGAAAAA
TGTTTCGAATTCACCATATGC
AGTCGCAGCGGGTGCTCCAGC
```

Gives results of:

```
TT =>  2
AAA =>  1
TT =>  4
AAA =>  1
TT =>  2
TT =>  4
AAA =>  1
TT =>  2
TT =>  5
AAA =>  1
TT =>  1
AAA =>  2
TT =>  1
TT =>  2
```

When for this sample data set i would like a cumulative tally of every sequence, rather than number of individual occurrences in each matching string, like this:

```
AAA =>  6
TT => 23
```

How do i go about changing the output? And how do i prevent a string of TTTTT bases showing up as  TT =>  2? Then if anyone has any recommendations of how to go about the original problem/if it is even possible, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regular expression:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $char = 11;  # Looking for the 11th character, or position 10.

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (m{
        ( (.) \2*+ )        #  Look for a repeated character sequence
        (?<= .{$char} )     #  Must include pos $char - 1
    }x) {
        printf "%s => %d\n", $2, length($1);
    }
}

__DATA__
ATTTTTAGCCGAACAAGTACC
TACTTAGTTAAATTGTTACAA
ATAAACCTTGTGCAGGTTTGT
CCTTAATCCTTGTATTTTTAA
TCTTGTTAAAATGTCTACAGG
ATGTTAGTTATTTCATTCTTC
AAGTAACTAAAATTGCTCAAT
ACATTCGACAAAAATGAAAAA
TGTTTCGAATTCACCATATGC
AGTCGCAGCGGGTGCTCCAGC
```

Output:

```
G => 1
A => 3
T => 1
T => 2
A => 4
T => 3
A => 4
A => 5
T => 2
G => 3
```

Comment: That seems so simple but works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you need. There really isn't a regular expression that will find the longest sequence of a given character at and around a given character position. This code works by splitting the string `$seq` into an array of characters `@seq` and then searching forwards and backwards from the centre.

It's practical to do things this way because the sequence is relatively short, and as long as there's an odd numbers of characters in the string it will calculate the centre point for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($base, $length) = find_mid_band($_);
  printf "%s => %d\n", $base, $length;
}


sub find_mid_band {
  my ($seq) = @_;
  my @seq = unpack '(A1)*', $seq;

  my $len_seq = @seq;
  my $c_offset = ($len_seq - 1) / 2;
  my $c_char = $seq[$c_offset];

  my ($start, $end) = ($c_offset, $c_offset + 1);
  --$start while $start > 0        and $seq[$start-1] eq $c_char;
  ++$end   while $end   < $len_seq and $seq[$end]     eq $c_char;

  return $c_char, $end-$start;
}

__DATA__
ATTTTTAGCCGAACAAGTACC
TACTTAGTTAAATTGTTACAA
ATAAACCTTGTGCAGGTTTGT
CCTTAATCCTTGTATTTTTAA
TCTTGTTAAAATGTCTACAGG
ATGTTAGTTATTTCATTCTTC
AAGTAACTAAAATTGCTCAAT
ACATTCGACAAAAATGAAAAA
TGTTTCGAATTCACCATATGC
AGTCGCAGCGGGTGCTCCAGC
```

**output**

```
G => 1
A => 3
T => 1
T => 2
A => 4
T => 3
A => 4
A => 5
T => 2
G => 3
```

---

**Update**

Here's a better way. It's shorter and faster, and works by all the subsequences of the same character until it finds a sequence that spans the middle character.

The output is identical to that of the above.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($base, $length) = find_mid_band($_);
  printf "%s => %d\n", $base, $length;
}


sub find_mid_band {
  my ($seq) = @_;
  my $mid_seq = length($seq) / 2;
  while ( $seq =~ /(.)\1*/g ) {
    if ($-[0] < $mid_seq and $+[0] > $mid_seq) {
      return $1, $+[0]-$-[0];
    }
  }
}

__DATA__
ATTTTTAGCCGAACAAGTACC
TACTTAGTTAAATTGTTACAA
ATAAACCTTGTGCAGGTTTGT
CCTTAATCCTTGTATTTTTAA
TCTTGTTAAAATGTCTACAGG
ATGTTAGTTATTTCATTCTTC
AAGTAACTAAAATTGCTCAAT
ACATTCGACAAAAATGAAAAA
TGTTTCGAATTCACCATATGC
AGTCGCAGCGGGTGCTCCAGC
```

Comment: Since I finished coding, I noticed that you've added to your question and included some more sample data. I've changed my program to analyse that data, but I can't see what you mean by *"I would like a cumulative tally of every sequence, rather than number of individual occurrences in each matching string"*. Has this answer resolved your problem or do you still need something else?

Comment: Your reply has answered my question perfectly, thank you! The question about cumulative tallies was just for the code i had tried to start with, you've actually provided the script that will allow me to progress with my project which is really useful, cheers. I didn't have a clue where to start with counting the repeated bases around the centre, so to start with i just crudely counted occurrences of certain strings in the sequence.